How to determine COS version of a deployed Python Cloud Function to debug security vulnerability report?
I am trying to figure out the root cause and a remedy path of a security vulnerability that is flagged by the GCP security scanner for one of my GCP Python Cloud Functions.
NOTE:
I understand that Cloud Functions deployment/containers are supposed to be used as "black magic" with no knowledge of internals (as explained here:  SO similar question) - but this mode of operation fails when GCP's own security scanning is reporting security vulnerabilities on its own containers - and redeployment of CFs does not "solve" the problem. Thus, I am trying to dig deeper to understand how it actually works.
What is puzzling in this case is that, while my CF is a Python one - the security flag came for a Go library:
CVE-2024-24790 - Critical
Package: go 
Package type: Go stdlib

First, all my questions - and then below are details of why and how  I am trying to find the answers , and where I've got so far (not too far :(  )

Main question 1: how can one find which specific COS (Container Optimized OS) version is used to host a specific Cloud Function? (see below why I think it is important)
Main question 2: how to force GCP deploy to use the latest container image ? I see available container images for Python 39 and 310 runtimes as of 07/07/2024 (Tag = python39_20240707_3_9_19_RC00) but an older image is used based on what I see in the container build logs (v-python39_20240630_3_9_19_RC00) ?
Other sub-questions that I think will help to find the root of the problem:


is it possible to specify which COS to use when deploying your CF via 'gcloud deploy' command?




how to find which COS is used in a specific CF Runtime docker container image  - that are published here:  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#python




given a running Docker container with Ubuntu (specific to some Runtime version of Python) - how can I find if there is Go installed and what version? Disclaimer: I know nothing about Go, so this might be a very simple question! See below my attempts of finding this out - but basically I pulled the image and ran a container from it locally - 'sh' to it - and tried to search for 'go' or 'stdlib'  via 'find' and 'dpkg' - didn't find any. 'go' is also not on PATH.



Details:
Why COS:
Since my CF is Python, with no Go dependencies - it is clear that the Go library came into play from somewhere down the stack - most likely the container that hosts my CF. Searching Google docs for any mention of this specific vulnerability led me to this link: https://cloud.google.com/release-notes
where I noticed this entry:
July 01, 2024
Container Optimized OS
Security: Upgraded dev-lang/go to v1.21.11. This fixes CVE-2024-24790 and CVE-2024-24789.

So, breadcrumb #1: I need to use COS older than 07/01/2024 !
But, how do I find which COS is used? - that info I could not find, thus the question #1.
Digging further - back to the Vulnerability info:
CVE-2024-24790 - Critical
Package: go 
Package type: Go stdlib

Clicking through to the "VIEW FIX" link - shows more info:
Fixed in: 1.21.11
Details: Version 1.21.7
Affected location:  cpe:/o:canonical:ubuntu_linux:18.04
Package: go
Package type: Go stdlib
File location(s):   /cnb/lifecycle/launcher 
…

Breadcrumb #2: looks like this deployed CF is running on a container that  is using Ubuntu 18.04 with Go stdlib version of 1.21.7 - but the fix is in the stdlib version 1.21.11
Next step: find a version of Runtime that has Go stdlib version 1.21.11
easier said than done: could not find this info directly, but:
What I could find is what specific Runtime version and Docker image is most likely used for deployed CFs:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#python
has links to docker images for each supported Python version:

clicking on the image link - gives you the latest image IDs:
Latest python310 images:

-- BTW - today is 07/15/2024 - so 7 days ago would be at least 07/08/2024 - why is 07/02/2024 date in the Tag??
Latest python39 images:

This image ID could also be spotted in the CF container build logs:
"timestamp": "2024-07-11T14:57:24.194595801Z",
"severity": "INFO",
"labels": {
  "build_step": "Step #0 - \"fetch\"",
  "build_tags": "p-gcf,r-python39,v-python39_20240630_3_9_19_RC00,b-python_20240708_RC00"
 }

Interesting that even though I deployed my CF on 07/11/2024 - it did not use the latest image from 07/07/2024, but rather from 06/30/2024 …
Deploying on 07/15/2024 - same result - an older Docker image for the container seems to be used:
textPayload: "Step #2 - "build": Adding image label google.run-image: us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/serverless-runtimes/google-18-full/runtimes/python39:python39_20240630_3_9_19_RC00"
timestamp: "2024-07-15T10:05:36.600844638Z"

And the security scan still reports the same vulnerability present.
Assumption: latest versions of the container images, created AFTER 07/01/2024, should NOT have this vulnerability  - based on the release note about COS, where it says that the CVE-2024-24790 vulnerability was fixed in the COS on 07/01/2024
Since I could not force GCP to deploy my CF using the latest container version available:
Next step: build and run a Docker container from the latest images locally - both 07/07/2024 (python39) and 07/02/2024 (python310) - and see what version of Go and 'stdlib' are installed
Results: could not find anything 'go'-related, but since I have never used Go - I might be doing this wrong - this is what I tried:
python39 runtime - container created from the latest image, then 'sh' to the running instance:
confirmed Ubuntu version of the container:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
$

search for installed 'go' packages/libs:
$ dpkg -l | grep go
-- nothing related to Go

$ dpkg -l | grep std
-- also nothing related to Go - here are full results:
ii  libpython3-stdlib:amd64           3.6.7-1~18.04                               amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
ii  libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64         3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13+esm1                amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.6)
ii  libstdc++6:amd64                  8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04                        amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  libzstd1:amd64                    1.3.3+dfsg-2ubuntu1.2                       amd64        fast lossless compression algorithm
$

Next step: Assumption: since Python3.9 runtime is on Ubuntu18.04, maybe the  Python3.10 runtime, which uses Ubuntu 20.04 (per https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#python) uses a later version of Go ??
Repeated the same steps as for python39 - redeployed CF with python310 runtime, built and ran local Docker container from the latest (07/02/2024) Docker image version
Same results:

same vulnerability is present
the 06/30/2024 container image is used when redeploying the CF
local container from 310 image - still do not see anything related to Go using 'find' and 'dpkg'

One difference between vulnerability report for python39 vs python310 deployed CFs:

in python39, the 'VIEW FIX' shows this location of the offender: Affected location:  cpe:/o:canonical:ubuntu_linux:18.04

in python310:
Fixed in:  1.21.11
Details: Version: 1.21.7
Affected location: Unsupported OS
Package: go
Package type: Go stdlib


Why "Unsupported OS" if GCP builds this Runtime container from its own "supported" images??
Also , it is still not clear how to match a specific Docker image  to a COS version - nothing about COS is logged anywhere, no docs either

Your concern is real and your questions are great. However, I can't answer them, it's very deep dive and you should reach Google Cloud PM directly to have this level of detail and expertise. Nevertheless, your Cloud Functions container runs into a sandboxed environment (GVisor) and it should protect your container against this kind of CVE. So, in reality, you risk exposure is minimal, even if your concern to solve sec issue is the right way!

thank you, @guillaumeblaquiere , it's good to know about the sandbox env! And you confirmed I'm not going crazy in circles here :)

Seems like your issue needs to be inspected at project level and in-depth analysis is required to check the route cause. I recommend to contact Google Support

We have the same issue, and we have raised support ticket. We can clearly see the issue and potential solution but we don't know what we can do to fix it. Google support team could not help too. So they sent it to product team. I can send the ticket numbers. In short, it does not look like a project level issue but wider.

thank you, Avi! yes, it is a not a project level issue at all - as we see the same issue in 3 projects - ENG, QA and PROD. The issue is clearly that the new COS is not being used to create a new runtime container for a CF when redeployed ... Yes, please post your ticket issue - it will be very helpful!  Our support (SADA) just forwarded us to an already opened Google issue that I have commented on: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/350528351?pli=1

Solution:
Wait for 1 month - and then a redeploy of your CF finally gets a container with the fixed vulnerability! :)
Deployed on 08/16/2024 - and no more security warnings.
